# Как сделать активный класс по клику?

Tags: vue.js

помогите пожалуйста. У меня есть
`<li class="choose_number">1</li>`
`<li class="choose_number">2</li>`
Как сделать так, что бы при клике активировался класс choose_number-active ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Согласно документации - [Работа с классами и стилями](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html)  :

> Для динамической установки или удаления CSS-классов можно передавать
> объект в директиву `v-bind:class`
>
> `<div v-bind:class="{ active: isActive }"></div>`
>
> Запись выше означает, что наличие класса `active` будет определяться истинностью параметра `isActive`

Добавлю только, что вместо параметра `isActive` вы можете использовать выражение, при истинности которого будет присвоен класс СSS соответствующему элементу

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => {
    return {
      activeEl: 0,
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.choose_number-active {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li class="choose_number" :class="{'choose_number-active': activeEl===1}" @click="activeEl = 1">1</li>
    <li class="choose_number" :class="{'choose_number-active': activeEl===2}" @click="activeEl = 2">2</li>
  </ul>
  или

  <ul>
    <li v-for="i in 10" class="choose_number" :class="{'choose_number-active': activeEl===i}" @click="activeEl = i">Элемент {{ i }}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```